# Break loop in recursive function after finding variable python

Tags: python, list, recursion

I know that this subject has been discussed in detail but my use case is somewhat special.

Problem description: I am trying to analyze a tree which has multiple layers. Each layer may consists of  of elements and these elements, when accessed may contain further expandable elements (lists) or just a simple element (non-list). Basically it's like the Windows / Linux folders and files system.  Maybe following schema will help to better understand what I'm referring to:

```
[Parent_Element]
|
+ [Element 1]
  |
  + [Subelement 1.1]
    + Subsubelement 1.1.1
    |
    + [hello_world]
      |
      Subsubsubelement 1.1.2.1
      |
      Subsubsubelement 1.1.2.2
    |
    + Subsubelement 1.1.3
  |
  + [Subelement 1.2]
    |
    + Subsubelement 1.2.1
  |  
  + Subelement 1.3
|
+ [Element 2]
  |  
  + Subelement2.1
|
+ Element 3
```

I tried to use the following code which is partially working the way I intend it to. The problem is that my code keeps running also after finding the desired search_variable of "hello_world". It would be nice to be able to stop the code when finding this variable for the first time.

```
def search_function(parent_element, search_variable = "hello_world"):
    # Get elements of parent_element
    elements = parent_element.get_elements()
    #
    # Check if Parent_Element has subelements
    # TRUE: Parent_Element is LIST
    # FALSE: Parent_Element is not a LIST
    if isinstance(elements, list):
        #
        # Loop over each elem of the parent_element and 
        for elem in elements:
            # Check if elem has the desired name
            # TRUE: Save elem
            if elem.get_display_name().to_string() == search_variable:
                print("Search Successful!")
                return elem
                break
            #
            # FALSE: Keep on looking in the sub-elements
            else:
                search_function(elem)
                break
    else:
        pass
#
```

Comment: What is "second_trial_function"?

Comment: Sorry, that should be the search_function(). Thank you, I will update the question.

Answer (score 0):

'break' will never be executed in your code. You should have to use a `flag` and make it `global`. `break` is after `return` that's why `break` never execute.

```
if elem.get_display_name().to_string() == search_variable:
    print("Search Successful!")
    return elem
    break
```

Use another if statement at the same level as the previous one to control it. You may edit your code like this.

```
           
        for elem in elements:
            # Check if elem has the desired name
            # TRUE: Save elem
            if elem.get_display_name().to_string() == search_variable:
                print("Search Successful!")
                flag = 1
                return elem

            #
            # FALSE: Keep on looking in the sub-elements
            else:
                second_trial_function(elem)
                break
    
            if flag : 
                break
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok so thanks to the response of @KittoMi I was able to finish my function:

```
def search_function(input_node, search_variable = "hello_world"):
    global x
    global searched_elem
    #
    elements = input_node.get_children()
    #
    if isinstance(elements, list):
        for elem in elements:
            #
            print(elem)
            if elem.get_display_name().to_string() == search_variable:
                x = 1
                print("Found it!")
                print(elem)
                searched_elem = str(elem)
                return searched_elem
                #
            else:
                search_function(elem, search_variable=search_variable)
            if x:
                break
    else:
        pass
    #
```

But I must admit that I still don't fully understand why it didn't work without the *global searched_elem*.

The function was finding the search variable, it printed the "Found it" message but then it performed on its own further 2-3 calculations and the result displayed was another that the one expected.
Here a small example of the returned print(elem):

```
hello_world
Found!
hello_world
other_elem
yet_another_elem
```

This is why I had to resort tot the *global searched_elem*. Maybe someone can clarify this.